# laravel Undefined property: stdClass::$

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

how I can correct this error, I have three tables profils, competences and competences_profil.
I want to recover the competences of each profil, I could retrieve the profils with query builder and competences with eloquent. but when I want to retreive the competence of each profil, I get following error : Undefined property: $ stdClass ::

```
controller :
        $competences = \App\Competence::All();

     $profils = \DB::table('profils')
            ->select(['profils.*']);

        if($request->has('varcate')){
                $profils->join('fonctions','profils.fonctions_id','=','fonctions.id');       
                $profils->join('categos','fonctions.categos_id','=','categos.id');
                $profils->where('categos.id','=',$request->input('varcate'));

        }

        if($request->has('varfonction')){
            if(!$request->has('varcate')){   
                $profils->join('fonctions','profils.fonctions_id','=','fonctions.id');       
            }

            $profils->where('fonctions.id','=',$request->input('varfonction'));
        }

        if($request->has('varstate')){
                $profils->join('citys','profils.citys_id','=','citys.id');       
                $profils->join('states','citys.state_id','=','states.id');
                $profils->where('states.id','=',$request->input('varstate'));

        }

     if($request->has('varcity')){
            if(!$request->has('varstate')){   
                $profils->join('citys','profils.citys_id','=','citys.id');       
            }

            $profils->where('citys.id','=',$request->input('varcity'));
        }

      $profils = $profils->paginate(30);
```

model :
    competence
            public function profils()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Profils');
        }

```
profils
        public function competences()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Competence');
    }

view :
@foreach($profils as $profil) 
        @foreach($profil->competences as $competence) 
          {{$competence->titre}}
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

controller :

```
    use App/Profils

public function getProfiles(Profils $profils){

    $profils = $profils;

    if($request->has('varcate')){

        $varcate = $request->get('varcate');
        $profils =  $profils->whereHas('fonctions', function ($query) use ($varcate){
                        $query->whereHas('category', function ($subQuery) use ($varcate) {
                                $subQuery->where('category.id',$varcate);
                        });
                    });
    }

    if($request->has('varfonction')){

        $varfonction = $request->get('varfonction');
        $profils =  $profils->whereHas('fonctions', function ($query) use ($varfonction){
                        $query->where('fonctions.id',$varfonction);
                });
    }

    if($request->has('varstate')){

        $varstate = $request->get('varstate');
        $profils =  $profils->whereHas('citys', function ($query) use ($varstate){
                        $query->whereHas('states', function ($subQuery) use ($varstate) {
                                $subQuery->where('states.id',$varstate);
                        });
                    });
    }

    if($request->has('varcity')){

        $varcity = $request->get('varcity');
        $profils =  $profils->whereHas('citys', function ($query) use ($varcity){
                        $query->where('citys.id',$varcity);
        });

    }


    $profils = $profils->paginate(30);

    return view('profiles',compact('profils'))
}
```

profils

```
 public function fonctions(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\fonctions','fonctions_id');
}

public function citys(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\citys','citys_id');
}

public function competences()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Competence');
}
```

fonction

```
public function fonction(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\category','category_id');
}
```

citys

```
public function states(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\states','state_id');
}
```

view :

```
@foreach($profils as $profil) 
        @foreach($profil->competences as $competence) 
          {{$competence->titre}}
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: You mean I have to change my $profiles querybuilder to elequont?
before I did not copy the entire Requet, please find above the complete request.

Comment: you can convert all the request in the similar eloquent way

Comment: the same thing for : lwillaya, lmetier and lcommune, no change?